# Can we get exclusive pokemon from our game counterpart using ultra wormhole?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

We can enter to to alternate world from altar of moone/sunne using ultra wormhole with Lunala's/Solgaleo's power.

In this alternate world, it seems that the in-game time is changed. 
When I'm enter ultra wormhole at the day, the alternate world is set time to night.
Is it only change the time or also change the probability to get exclusive pokemon from pokemon sun?

For Example, I'm playing pokemon moon, we can catch Oranguru in Lush Jungle but not Passimian because Passimian is exclusive pokemon for pokemon sun.
If we travel to alternate world, would the change of ecounter also swapped so we can catch Passimian in pokemon moon, or is it only change the in-game time?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot catch Pokemon from the counterpart game by using the wormhole.

Source: I have tried it before.